# Rails. View trips/1, in the view I have a promise, when it's resolved, I am redirected to trips/[object%20Object]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, promise

Very hard to explain:

I am in trips/1 (in the show page of a trip). I make a call to the geocoding API from Google:

```
<script>
  const url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=munich&key=AIzaaaabo"

  fetch(url).then(response =>
    response.json().then(data => ({
        data: data,
        status: response.status
    })
  ).then(res => {
    location = res.data.results[0].geometry.location;
  }));
</script>
```

Somehow, when the promise is resolved, I got redirected to

http://localhost:3000/trips/[object%20Object]

Which of course causes an error.

I really don't get what's going on.

Any help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you paste the response of `console.log(location);`? My guess is the window.location object is being replaced. Might be wrong.

Comment: uau, totally right. I replaced location for location2 and all fine. Why on earth Rails did a new request / redirection if I use a variable named location? It's not that I used window.location or sth like this. Thanks thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp , `location` is a reserved keyword. As mentioned in the comment, assigning the variable as something other than `location` does the trick. Happy to help.